# A RewriteRule is completely ignored for some paths

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a simple Apache RewriteRule like this:

`RewriteRule (.*) deploying.html [L]`

Which is supposed to display the `deploying.html` file for any request.

It works for every path except for one. `/current_foo/` works, while `/current/` displays a classic 404 page. Both the `current_foo` and `current` folders are absolutely non-existent, and yet the result is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason Apache behaves differently with the `/current/` path, is that **there exists a folder named `current.tmp`** as well. I just had to remove the dot. Then the `/current/` path works as expected.

This behaviour is due the Multiviews option, which looks around for similar paths excluding the "extension." Adding **`Options -MultiViews`** in the .htaccess disables this option and fixes the issue.

See this article : https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2218-negotiation-discovered-file-s-matching-request-none-could-be-negotiated.htm